# Импорт библиотеки GrymCore

Tags: winapi, com, c++11, c++, dll

Здравствуйте! Сейчас пишу плагин для 2gis...

[Реализация модуля расширения в виде DLL библиотеки](http://plugins.2gis.ru/wiki/CreateDLLModule)

Вот здесь Библиотека типов GrymCore сказано:

> Библиотека включена в главный модуль приложения Grym.exe и регистрируется в операционной системе при первом запуске приложения

Я так понял, что после того, как один раз запустил Grym.exe, могу обращаться
к пространству имен `GrymCore::`, и Visual Studio 2010 должна вывести всевозможные имена из этого пространства имён...Что у меня не происходит

Visual Studio подчеркивает все слова `GrymCore::` волнистой линией с всплывающей подсказкой:

"Имя, за которым следует выражение "::", должен определять класс или пространство имён"

На шаге 3.1 [инструкции](http://plugins.2gis.ru/wiki/CreateDLLModule) добавляю импорт библиотеки GrymCore

```
#import "libid:7AA02C95-0B4A-43aa-92D8-BA40511A7F3F"
```

`import` подчёркнут волнистой линией с всплывающей подсказкой:

"не удаётся открыть источник файл "C:/.../[Папка с решением]/Debug/libid:7AA02C95-0B4A-43aa-92D8-BA40511A7F3F" "

Компилируется нормально, плагин в 2gis работает

Как исправить, чтобы ничего не подчеркивалось, и мог обращаться к пространству имён `GrymCore::` и не писать вручную каждый раз имя интерфейса, а только начало имени...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил заменой на

```
#import "E:\Program Files\2gis\3.0\grym.exe" rename("RemoveDirectory", "GrymRemoveDirectory")
```

не знаю насколько правильно